# Enviar Label.textContent como parametro en un @Url.Action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hola gente soy novato en MVC y tengo una cuestión, ¿es posible pasar el texto de un Label como parametro?

Mi idea, es que desde el ese btn, enviar al controlador el texto de la etiqueta y luego utilizarlo en el controlador. El punto es, ¿como lo obtengo?, ya que no me permite recoger el valor por el Id

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que el el View se conecta al Controlles es haciendo llamadas.
Post o Get.. para ello necesitas tener un formulario y un boton tipo submit.

Aunque no le veo sentido, ¿para qué quieres enviar algo que no es modificable? eso significa que le asignas valor desde código.

Para enviar los valores al controller, utilizamos la porpiedad name de los input.

Así que si quieres darle apariencia de etiqueta a un input, podrías hacer algo como esto: (en el View)

```
<input type="text" name="miTexto" value="Este es el Contenido" style="border:none;background:none;" readonly>
```

Y luego en el controller, puedes acceder a este valor

```
 public ActionResult Index( string miTexto)
        {            
            return View();
        }
```